# Majority Voter for complex data

Tags: reliability, redundancy

How is a majority voter for complex data implemented?
If there is only one integer value which should be compared you can use a discrete circuit but how does it work for multiple datasets and floating values which could be slightly different because of rounding effects.

Is the voter itself a microcontroller and a single point of failure ?
How are the voting results send for example on a can bus?

Comment: why would two identical calculations be different?!?

Comment: Maybe because you are using different controllers with different libraries and different precision

Comment: you'd almost certainly never do that!

Comment: Voting can only be done on deterministic processes. Which most everything is. If rounding the same number with the same flags turned on in a processor, the answer must be the same. You can't use different processors.

Comment: Okay this makes sense.

Comment: But how do you compare a stream of outputs?  The controllers do not necessarily start their output at the exact same time right?

Comment: @BigStorm as Voltage Spike said, you can only vote on deterministic things. If your data synchronization is non-deterministic, you need to fix that.